# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]' guard let when shuffled

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, avaudioplayer, shuffle

I got problem with shuffling sounds. When I got `guard let sound = sounds.shuffled(),` it gets me an error `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]'`

Any idea how to fix this? Is it because of guard let? Here is my code:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

@IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let sounds = ["x", "y", "z"].shuffled()

        guard let sound = sounds.shuffled(),
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sound, withExtension: "mp3") else { return }


        do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
            audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: `sounds.shuffled()` isn't returning an optional value. ie: it can't be nil. So you can't unwrap it with an `if let` or a `guard let`, so put it above: `let sound = sounds.shuffled(); guard let soundURL = Bundle... else { return }`

Comment: Why are you putting `sound = sounds.shuffled()` into the guard clause? Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: Please read your code. It makes no sense to shuffle the array twice and the return value is not a single element. It’s a copy&paste mistake. You mean `guard let sound = sounds.randomElement(),...` but strictly spoken this shuffles the array twice, too. You can delete (the first) `.shuffled()`

Comment: @Sweeper guard to transfer program control out of a scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use

```
guard let sound = sounds.first
```

which picks the first element out of the shuffled array (which can be nil if the array is empty).

Alternatively you can remove the shuffle and just use

```
guard let sound = ["x", "y", "z"].randomElement()
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer. But when I use randomElement() it would reapeat sounds, which I dont want :)

Answer (score 1):

`sounds.shuffled()` does not return an optional thus the linter tells you not to guard it because it doesn't make any sense. Read about it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994757-shuffled

```swift
let sound = sounds.shuffled()
```

This also seems wrong. `let sound` suggest that you want just one of the sounds, shuffle returns the array of sounds - just shuffled. What you could do is to use `.first` which returns on optional sound (optional because the array could be empty). Read here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689165-first

```swift
guard let sound = sound.first, ... else { return }
```

Comment: Of course it works, not my day, thank you very much! I would remember it :)